# Parse out XML Value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, parsing

I have the following XML contained in a column `XML_TRANSACTION` in a table `TRANSACTION` in SQL Server. I am trying to parse out the information inside the `From` and `To` tags into separate columns:

```
<Transaction Id="1234" Timestamp="2012-04-28T05:02:20" Version="TransactionVersion2" SenderId="abcd" SenderLocId="vxyz">
      <Instance Name="Home" />
      <Messages>
        <Message Id="0" Timestamp="2014-04-28T01:00:46">
          <MessageRequest Name="Movement" Xsd="Movement.xsd" Version="5">
            <Body>
              <Parts>
                <Part PartNumber="11111" Qty="1" PersonUniqueId="A1B2C3" />
              </Parts>
              <Order Number="13579" Uid="01" />
              <Ship Number="1ZW23" Type="Out" />
              <From VendorId="XY1X2" VendorLocId="XY1X2" VendorName="Vendor_Extra" VendorStockRoom="OPEN" CountryCode="US" />
              <To VendorId="XY1X2" VendorLocId="XY1X2" VendorName="Vendor_Extra" VendorStockRoom="CLOSED" CountryCode="US" />
            </Body>
          </MessageRequest>
        </Message>
      </Messages>
    </Transaction>
```

Desired results:

```
From_VendorID || From_VendorLocID || From_VendorName || To_VendorID || To_VendorLocID
--------------++------------------++--------------------------------------------------
XY1X2         || XY1X2            || Vendor_Extra    || XY1X2       || XY1X2
```

etc.

I have made several attempts, but have been unsuccessful.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the datatype of the field? I assumed XML, but you never know.

Comment: The field value is XML.

Comment: SELECT Evt.value('To/@VendorId') as To_VendorId FROM tblTRANSACTION CROSS APPLY transaction_xml.nodes('/Transaction/Messages/Message/MessageRequest/Body') as Tbl(Evt)

Comment: I also tried:

declare @data xml ='dbo.tblTRANSACTION.TRANSACTION_XML';

with xmlnamespaces(default 'dbo.tblTRANSACTION.TRANSACTION_XML')

select t.c.value('@VendorID', 'int') as To_VendorId

from @data.nodes('To') as t(c)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT 
t.[XML_TRANSACTION].value('(//From/@VendorId)[1]','varchar(20)') as From_VendorID
,t.[XML_TRANSACTION].value('(//From/@VendorLocId)[1]','varchar(20)') as From_VendorLocID 
,t.[XML_TRANSACTION].value('(//To/@VendorLocId)[1]','varchar(20)') as To_VendorLocID 
,t.[XML_TRANSACTION].value('(//To/@VendorLocId)[1]','varchar(20)') as To_VendorLocID 
FROM [CD].[TEST] AS t
```

Comment: One word of caution: using the `//From` XPath expression is a killer of performance - it'll parse the whole XML document over and over again. Try to use **more specific**, more precise XPath expression for better performance and for less surprising results!